# create a widget above all in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dialog

[image]

how to create a new widget that floating on the top of all widgets, I used stack to achieve this function， but when I used showGeneralDialog to open a pop-window, this widget is below dialog, how to let it above dialog like that demo?

Comment: tried using `OverlayEntry`?

Comment: Why not use Stack instead of dialog?

Comment: I used this flutter_portal from pub dev to solve my issue. @pskink